# TFS setup related issues

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is there any focused documentation on achieving the following with TFS. I find myself having to read through tonnes of documentation on MSDN and I find nothing is listed under topics as such or maybe I don't know what to look for. I have no experience in TFS other than checking files in and out and I am still trying to understand what each of these mean and how to find it in the docs, without much luck.

1. Gated check-in + continuous build for select projects.
2. Gated check-in + scheduled builds for other select projects.
3. Dashboards and reporting to select individuals or groups
4. Access for testing team members to only selective work item creation of the TFS project they are assigned to. They
   should be able to get the latest version of the code and be able to log a workitem-bug, workitem-issue, workitem-testcase but they should not be able to create for eg. workitem:use case.
5. Testers should not be able to modify code.
6. Sending mails to persons who have a work item assigned to them, with
   select persons in copy.
7. Sending of emails to anyone against whom a bug is assigned. When bug
   is closed the person who raised the bug should get notified via
   email.
8. Sending mails to key persons of a project defined somewhere in TFS,
   on build failure of that project.

If anyone has already done something like any of the points listed above then can you please let me know the steps? Somehow the documentation jumping too many links and going in various tangents.

Thanks for your time and patience..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order:

1. Go to the Microsoft TFS site at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx. Look for the training videos. Most of the stuff you want is covered.
2. The *Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide* at http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/ is an excellent guide.
3. The *Introduction to Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 Training Kit* at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27152 is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the links. They will certainly be helpful when I am looking at a more relaxed learning environment. Right now I need to get 1,2,6,7,8 working asap; so looking for a bulleted set of instruction to acheive them right away. -Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the SDK is the way to go. I do know that alerts are fully customizable, but I am pretty sure there is no user-interface, except for the simple one provided under "Project Alerts..."

Comment: The TFS Power Tools has an Alert Explorer which is handy and the tools are a ***must*** have.